# Technique for diagonalising this free spinless fermionic Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, fermions

How does one diagonalise the following Hamiltonian?
$$
H = \sum_n \epsilon_n c^\dagger_n c_n + g \sum_n (c^\dagger_n c^\dagger_{-n} + c_{-n}c_n),
$$
where $c_n$ is a spineless fermionic op. Clearly we need to define a transformation that mixes the $c_n$'s with the $c^\dagger_n$'s but the standard Bogoliubov transformation doesn’t work as if
$$
f_n \doteq u_n c_n + v_n c^\dagger_n
$$
then in order for the $f_n$'s to be canonical we demand
$$
|u_n|^2+|v_n|^2=1 \quad u_n v_n =0
$$
i.e. so $u_k=0$ or/and $v_k=0$. But then this wouldn’t diagonalise $H$!

So the usual Bogoliubov transformation doesn’t work with spinless fermions (I’m not claiming a more general doesn’t).

**How do we do it then?**

Comment: What about something like $u_nc_n+v_nc_{-n}^\dagger$?

Comment: The first appendix in the classic Lieb-Schultz-Mattis paper goes over diagonalizing general quadratic fermionic Hamiltonians: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491661901154